# Oracle regex expression sorting out special characters and Czech characters

Tags: regex, oracle, character, special-characters

Due to a interface with a bank I need to sort out some unwanted characters from a name field:

This is the permitted range:
0 - 9, a - z, A - Z, / - ? ( ) . , ' + (space) – but no Czech characters allowed

I've tried something like this getting unwanted hits on several period . and spaces, but not getting there 100%:

```
SELECT CASE
          WHEN  REGEXP_LIKE (name,
                            '^([0-9a-zA-Z]* *+(|_|\-|\.))')
          THEN
             'true'
          ELSE
             'false'
       END AS tmp, avt.*
  FROM amcbankvendtable avt
```

In addition I still havent removed czech characters. I know that the parameter character class `==a==` gives `ä` , but in this case I want the opposite, not allow `ûü`, but only `u`. (Basically only allow the english alpabeth).

So:

- 123456abc is okay
- 123û  is not okay
- 123#& is not okay (#& not allowed characters)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an expression like:

```
[^0-9a-zA-Z/?().,' +-]
```

If it matches than there is something which is not allowed.

Comment: false InteleSMS AS
false Protego AS
true Moraviapress  a.s.
true AB Facility  a.s. getting close.    WHEN  REGEXP_LIKE (name,
                               '[^0-9a-zA-Z/?().,+-] ') why is getting true on the 2 last occurences, is because of the two periods : .

Comment: @Trond - because Qtax forgot to add space character inside brackets.

Comment: but the apostrope, how do I get it working: [^0-9a-zA-Z/?(). ,''+-],  I tried quoting twice '' and escaping it, but do not get any hits on it.